# How to parse JSON which contains text in "Abrabic Language"?

Tags: xcode4.2

I am using following code to parse JSON-

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *JsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"New str - %@",newStr);

NSDictionary *response = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[JsonData bytes]] JSONValue];

NSLog(@"%@",response);
```

and this response is giving "null value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all add this in your Json file - (if that is a PHP file) (I think there might be error..)

```
<?
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8');

?>
```

And use Json like this -

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yout link to json file"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"new str - %@",newStr);



NSDictionary *response = [newStr JSONValue];

NSLog(@"json dictionary - %@",response);


NSLog(@"author - %@",[[[response objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"SportsNewList"] objectForKey:@"author"]);
```

Post comment if you face any issue